# How can I change color of dollar sign different than font-latex-math-face in auctex?

Tags: auctex, font-lock, math

In AUCTex, my `font-latex-math-face` has green color that also colors `$ $`  or `\( \)` into green as well. Here I just want to have different color for dollar sign than `font-latex-math-face`'s

[image]

Is it possible to change the color of dollar sign and `\( \)` into different color?

As example built-in math-mode at tex.stackexchange.com/ has this feature where dollar-sign shows up in different color:

[image]

Comment: It is bothersome to recreate text from screen.  Put the math in a text block, so that it is easy to copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this

***`$` math delimiter gets its own face***

[image: $ math delimiter gets its own face]

instead of this

***`$` math delimiter has same face math text***

[image: $ math delimiter has same face math text]

do this

```lisp
(defface font-latex-dollar-face
  '((t :foreground "lime green"))
  "Face for tikzpicture environment."
  :group 'font-latex-highlighting-faces)

(eval-after-load 'font-latex
  (advice-add
   'font-latex-match-dollar-math :around
   (defun font-latex-match-dollar-math--around
       (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
     (pcase-let*
         ((`(,limit)
           orig-args)
          (val (apply orig-fun orig-args))
          (beg (when val
                 (match-beginning 0)))
          (end (when val
                 (match-end 0))))
       (when (and beg
                  end
                  (save-excursion
                    (goto-char beg)
                    (looking-at-p (rx "$"))))
         (set-match-data
          (save-excursion
            (list
             (let* ((beg beg)
                    (end (progn (goto-char beg)
                                (skip-chars-forward (rx "$"))
                                (point))))
               (prog1 end
                 (add-text-properties beg end '(
                                                face font-latex-dollar-face
                                                fontified t))))
             (let* ((end end)
                    (beg (progn (goto-char end)
                                (skip-chars-backward (rx "$"))
                                (point))))
               (prog1 beg
                 (add-text-properties beg end '(face font-latex-dollar-face
                                                     fontified t)))))))
         val)))))

;; (advice-remove 'font-latex-match-dollar-math 'font-latex-match-dollar-math--around)
```

Comment: Even I read the manual I was not able to come up with this solution :-) I don't understand how it works but it works like magic, thanks.

Comment: How can this solution be extended to include `\(`, `\(`, `\[` and `\]`?